# how to setup Onpress On Textinput in react-native

Tags: react-native, textinput, onpress

I am developing an app on react native. I want to call a date picker when i press on a Text-Input and after selecting a date it should show on the Text-Input

Comment: Not sure to understand, if the user can't type text in the text input, why not use a button?

Comment: this is a special case

Comment: are you using any third party to open DatePicker? @StvNewsKaipamangalam

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot explicitly call `onPress` for `TextInput`. You could only use. `onFocus` which will be called when you press the input box to get cursor over there. **No need to focus on onBlur as your use case doesn't required.**. Handle close within `onFocus` if possible.

```
onFocus = () => {
  // do something
}

render() {
  <TextInput onFocus={onFocus} />
}
```

Answer (score 64):

Wrap `TextInput` into a view and set `pointerEvents` as `none`.
Now you can use `Pressable` component from `react-native` to listen to the `onpress` event.

```js
<Pressable onPress={() => alert('Hi!')}>
 <View pointerEvents="none">
  <TextInput />
 </View>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: this works for me because I also need it to be disable the TextInput, so only this answer works, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is use onFocus and onBlur of TextInput.

```
<TextInput 
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
/>

onFocus = () => {
 // Open date picker
}

onBlur = () => {
 // Close date picker and add value to textinput
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make text input field read only by providing

```
 editable={false}
 pointerEvents="none"
```

prop to TextInput.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap TextInput inside View and set pointerEvents="none", wrap that view with TouchableOpacity or any other Touchable Component. Please see below example!

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
                    alert('hello');
                }}>
                <View pointerEvents="none">
                    <TextInput
                        onChange={() => {}}
                        value={''}
                        placeholder={waterMark}
                        editable={!isDisabled}
                        selectTextOnFocus={!isDisabled}
                    />
                </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```